# How to prepare a statement like "CREATE TABLE <table_name> as select * from <another_table_name> where 1=2;"

Tags: java, jdbc

How to prepare a statement like "`CREATE TABLE <table_name> as select * from <another_table_name> where 1=2;`" where first table is from connected different sever and second table is connected from another server in java.

Comment: I have two databases connected differently using ojdbc. So I want to create a duplicate table from database 1 to database 2 without data. How can I accomplish that using JDBC ?

Comment: You can't do this directly. You will need to explicitly program table creation and transferring data. If you are using Oracle for both sides, you might be able to use database-links instead to do this.